# How does a three team trade work?

Tags: baseball, mlb, transaction

Now that we are approaching the MLB trade deadline, I would like to ask some questions about unusual trades. The first is about three team trades.

Suppose a manager of team A goes to the manager of team B and says, I want Y from you and I'm willing to offer X. If they agree that X and Y are equivalent, and that a trade would benefit both sides, the deal is done.

But suppose the manager of Team B says, "I think that X is equivalent to Y, but that's not really what I want. But I think Team C will accept X in trade for Z, and Z is what I really want for Y." Then there is a possible three way trade if team C is really is willing to trade Z for X.

Is this how a three way trade gets done? Or are there other means/mechanisms?

Comment: Related question in regards to basketball (NBA): http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/why-would-a-team-choose-to-become-involved-in-a-multi-team-trade

Comment: @edmastermind29: I'd say that the dynamics of a four team trade are "different" (and far more complicated) than a three team trade. Think the difference between three SQUARED and four squared.

Comment: 3 SQUARED and 4 squared are still fundamentally done the same (multiply the number by itself). I think it's no different here: it just adds another team into the mix, which increases the complexity of understanding the trade.

Answer (score 6):

Three team trades are complicated, but they are done. Here's essentially how this goes down. We'll identify three teams here, team A, team B and team C. Team A and B are the primaries in the trade, team C will be our intermediary.

- Team A is in playoff contention, they desperately need a closer. But don't have the right players to pull off the trade directly with team B, but has players who are desirable to team C.
- Team B is out of contention, has a closer on an expiring contract, they don't want anyone in team A's system enough to trade their closer, but have had their eye on a couple of guys in Team C's system.
- Team C is usually out of contention as well, but can sometimes be in contention (it doesn't usually benefit a contending team to do this, but an out of contention team can do well in a trade like this).

So team A will send their players who weren't the right mix for team B to team C, and team C will send their players to team B, who will send the closer to team A.

A recently [revealed *potential* scenario](http://www.bleachernation.com/2014/07/18/friday-afternoon-fun-cubs-mariners-rays-in-a-david-price-three-team-deal/) actually has some interesting details and insights into this. The author there gets into the details, but it amounts to this:

- Tampa wants young, good positional talent for David Price
- Seattle doesn't have any, but has some decent young pitching
- Chicago has young near ML ready positional talent and needs young pitching

A deal like this that has Seattle sending young pitching to Chicago, Chicago sending young positional talent to Tampa and Tampa sending Price to Seattle *could* workout. However, it requires that all sides, *especially* the intermediary thinking they are getting a good deal. This is largely why these deals don't happen. If a team doesn't have the players to get a deal done directly, it's very difficult to convince a third party that to give up their prospects (or ML talent in some cases) for players who weren't good enough for the 2 parties to swap directly.

Comment: Ok, it seems like the "trick" is to find an appropriate intermediary "Team C" to complete the trade.

Comment: @TomAu That's pretty much it. For something like this to work, all the teams have to feel good about it, so Team C has to get something they like out of it. In the Cubs example I linked, there is no one (or even 2-3 pitchers) in Seattle's system that would cause them to drop in as an intermediary in that deal, giving up any of their top hitting prospects (Baez/Bryant/Alcantara/Almora/etc)